# MySQL NDB cluster maximum data size

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster, max

According to the limitations outlined at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-limitations.html, there can only be 48 data nodes.

Does that mean, with number of replicas 2, I can actually have only 24 nodes to store data?

If the data memory is, say 4GB, then, does it mean I can only store 24*4=~100GB?

If so, how can I set up a cluster to store TBs of data?

Comment: Why would your storage be limited to 4Gb?

Comment: @Phil, that was just taken arbitrarily.

Comment: A single node can store many many Terabytes of data - I don't really understand the problem/question?

Comment: @Phil, but the cluster configuration needs a value for DataMemory and/or IndexMemory which should be within available physical memory. How in that case will one be able to store terrabytes?

Comment: Modern x64 boxes can have several Terabytes of memory...

Answer (score 1):

Data does not have to be memory-resident in NDB.  (That limitation existed long ago.)  So, there is much more than 4GB limitation per pair of servers.